# Sentence with scrolling text and overlapping div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make scrolling text in the middle of a sentence with html and css. How do I make the second half of the sentence responsive to the scrolling text? I'm sure responsive is not even the correct phrase, but hopefully you will see what I mean..be nice, i'm learning! :)

I really think that should be enough detail on the issue but i'm trying to satisfy the minimum word count.

Thanks

```css
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #ff8800;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: left;
     display: inline;
}
/*Wrapper*/
.wrapper{
    
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Vertical Sliding*/
.slidingVertical{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
  
}
.slidingVertical span{
    animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #ff8800;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

/*topToBottom Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <section class="wrapper">

    <h2 class="sentence">number
      <div class="slidingVertical">
        <span>one</span>
        <span>two</span>
        <span>three</span>
        <span>four</span>
      </div>
    </h2>
    <h2 class="sentence">is the best</h2>


  </section>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to add `display: inline-block` for `.sentence` and `.slidingVertical`.

For `display: inline`, `margin` and `padding` are neglected.

```
.sentence {
    color: #ff8800;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.slidingVertical {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it still doesn't seem quite right. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/vrxns2yq/

Comment: Do you need like this? "number one is the best"